# User's avatar discord.py 2.0

Tags: discord.py

How to get member's avatar in discord.py v2?

Before, it was like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["av"])
async def avatar(ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"{avamember}")
    embed2.set_image(url=userAvatarUrl)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
```

Error I got:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

Thanks!

Comment: So it does not work anymore? If so: What does not work? Try to use `print` statements to see where the code gets stuck.

Comment: Edited. `CommandInvokeError.`

Comment: Why are you using `v2.0` though? `discord.py` has reached its end. The command works fine for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `avamember.avatar_url` with `avamember.avatar.url`.

Here's the link to the 2.0 docs if you're interested:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Asset

Comment: Also [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/apple502j/f75b4f24652f04de85c7084ffd73ec58) for more breaking changes